# Java windows Service starts a new process but I'm unable to see it (although it's present on Task Manager)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, windows-services, nssm

I have a java app (which I made windows service using nnsm) that sets up sockets on localhost. When a message is received by that app it opens internet explorer.

When I run the app using cmd (e.g java -jar myServer.jar) it works as expected. An internet explorer instance starts.

When the app is being set up as a windows service and receives a message, it opens internet explorer **but I'm unable to see it** (although it is visible in Task Manager).
I want the process to start on the local system and be able to see it and interact with it

Any help or idea would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A service is isolated from the session of any other logged on user and cannot perform that type of interaction; IE is launching in the service's session, not yours.  What would happen if there were 2 logged on users? Who would "win" IE?

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I bypassed the issue by making it a start-up application. Once the user starts the pc and logs in, the java-app starts to run and it works as expected